# How to get URL parameters in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, url-parameters

I'm using Vue, but *I'm not using vue-router*.

How can I get URI parameters?

I found one way to get URI by using root el property.

[image: screenshot]

But is there any proper way to get the parameters as I want to send them to 
backend and get a response from server and display it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are not using `vue-router`, I don't think you'll be able to access your params. So your only chance is to use the URL api as:

```
const url = new URL(window.location.href); 
const getParam = url.searchParams.get('foo');
```

This will give you the value of foo in `?foo=bar`

---

Alternatively, you can do something like this.

```
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 
 data () {
   return {
     params: window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf('?'))
   }
 },
 
 methods: {
   getParam (p) {
     let param = new URLSearchParams(this.params);
     if(param.has(p)){
       return param.get(p)
     }else{
       false
     }
   }
 },
})
```

Now, just get the param using `getParam('foo')`

Comment: thank you for the answer. I thought there is any other way around it.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the URL parameters by using window.location.search:

```js
const queryString = window.location.search;
console.log(queryString);
// ?product=troussers&color=black&newuser&size=s
```

For parsing  parameters of the query string, use URLSearchParams:

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
```

For more info, read this [tutorial](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-get-url-parameters.html).

Comment: That link is unfortunately dead.:/

Comment: I removed `/m` and now it is no longer dead.

Answer (score 0):

We don't use vue router for the moment either. We use the following script to parse args.

```
    var args = {};

    var argString = window.location.hash;
    //everything after src belongs as part of the url, not to be parsed
    var argsAndSrc = argString.split(/src=/);
    args["src"] = argsAndSrc[1];
    //everything before src is args for this page.
    var argArray = argsAndSrc[0].split("?");
    for (var i = 0; i < argArray.length; i++) {
        var nameVal = argArray[i].split("=");
        //strip the hash
        if (i == 0) {
            var name = nameVal[0];
            nameVal[0] = name.slice(1);
        }
        args[nameVal[0]] = decodeURI(nameVal[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Route properties are present in `this.$route`.

`this.$router` is the instance of router object which gives the configuration of the router.

You can get the current route query using this.$route.query

Comment: i am not using vue-router. and $route is not present in my case as it is created when using vue router. thats what i am asking is there any way around it.