# angular - determine how the client opened the link

Tags: angular

There is a method

```
    this.router.navigate([`${numer}`]).then(() => {});
```

this method is in the `footer` module. This method redirects to http://localhost:4200/7.

The page http://localhost:4200/7 is served by the `body` module.

My task is to determine how the client clicked on this link. For example: it was a direct link received by e-mail or it was the router.navigate method that worked.

Can you please tell me how to determine this?

I need to understand if the router.navigate method worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL params. Provide it as `<route>?param1=lorem&param2=ipsum`. You can then check the values of the params in any component by checking these params.

See [How to get URL parameters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47773022/how-to-get-url-parameters-in-javascript)